# Responsive Menu when nav loaded from other file with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a little project. To keep my files clean, I split them up into separate HTML files and I load them via Jquery. This always worked, but now when adding responsiveness. It won't work! When I put the code directly in the HTML, it works! Can someone help me?

PS: The file gets loaded in HTML because I can see the navbar, I just can't click the button to open the menu.

Here is my code:

navresponsive.html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close"><img src="images/close.png" alt="close icon" class="closeIcon"></a>
<a href="index.html" id="homepageResponsive">Thuispagina</a>
<a href="story.html" id="storyResponsive">Mijn Verhaal ;)</a>
<a href="pics.html" id="picsResponsive">Mijn foto's</a>
<a href="despacito.html" id="despacitoResponsive">Mijn despacito 2 cover</a>
```

story.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page!</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="./assets/pictures/salcosecond.ico">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="navResponsive" id="navResponsive">
    </div>

    <div class="nav" id="nav">
    </div>
</html>
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(() => {

// Navigation bar

$('#header').load('files/header.html');
$('#nav').load('files/nav.html');
$('#navResponsive').load('files/navresponsive.html');

// Responsive nav
  $(".open").click(function(){
    $(this).css("display", "none");
    $(".navResponsive").css("width", "100%");
  });

  $(".close").click(function(){
    $(".navResponsive").css("width", "0");
    $(".open").css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the contents are dynamically loaded, events will be attached way before your page is loaded into `DOM` wherein either you've to follow `event delegation` or work with `promises`.

**Event Delegation**

Change click event as below:

```
$(document).on('click',".open", function(){
   $(this).css("display", "none");
   $(".navResponsive").css("width", "100%");
});

$(document).on('click',".close", function(){
  $(".navResponsive").css("width", "0");
  $(".open").css("display", "block");
});
```

**Promises**

```
var promises = [];
promise.push($('#header').load('files/header.html'));
promise.push($('#nav').load('files/nav.html'));
promise.push($('#navResponsive').load('files/navresponsive.html'));

Promise.all(promise).then(function(){
  $(".open").click(function(){
    $(this).css("display", "none");
    $(".navResponsive").css("width", "100%");
  });

  $(".close").click(function(){
    $(".navResponsive").css("width", "0");
    $(".open").css("display", "block");
  });

});
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename navresponsive.html to navresponsive.php
2. Rename story.html to story.php, and edit:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page!</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="./assets/pictures/salcosecond.ico">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="navResponsive" id="navResponsive">
 
      <?php include('navresponsive.php'); ?>
    
    </div>

    <div class="nav" id="nav">
    </div>
</html>
```

3. Forgot the jQuery method. :)